# UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling new World()

Tags: java, libgdx

My error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jbox2d.common.Timer.now()D
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jbox2d.common.Timer.now()D
    at org.jbox2d.common.Timer.now(Native Method)
    at org.jbox2d.common.Timer.reset(Timer.java:35)
    at org.jbox2d.common.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:31)
    at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.<init>(World.java:587)
    at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.<init>(World.java:158)
    at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.<init>(World.java:154)
    at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.<init>(World.java:145)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<init>(World.java:61)
    at com.example.blockbunny.states.Play.<init>(Play.java:22)
    at com.example.blockbunny.handlers.GameStateManager.getState(GameStateManager.java:36)
    at com.example.blockbunny.handlers.GameStateManager.pushState(GameStateManager.java:46)
    at com.example.blockbunny.handlers.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:20)
    at com.example.blockbunny.main.Game.create(Game.java:33)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:146)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:123)
```

And this occurs when I do this:

```
world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);
```

I have looked online, and some solutions included using this:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader;
GdxNativesLoader.load();
```

However, I don't know where to put this function, and if it even works (I tried putting it in several different places)

How can I fix this issue?

Help will be appreciated, thanks!

As requested, here are my imports:

```
import static com.example.blockbunny.handlers.B2DVars.PPM;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.example.blockbunny.handlers.GameStateManager;
import com.example.blockbunny.main.Game;
```

Comment: hi, could you edit your post and put all imports that are at start of your class

Comment: @minos23 I added the imports now

Comment: i requested the the import to see if you are using other similar World class but you're not, i propose to you some solution to try hoping it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Box2d several time with libgdx and i never encountered such a problem :

here what i propose t you :

GdxNativesLoader.load();
should be put on the **create()** method, but that doesn't seem to work with you

also try call it in a static way like this :

```
static {
    GdxNativesLoader.load();
}
```

but i thin your problem is the extension of the library that you are using 
verify that you are using gdx-box2d and not gdx-box2d-gwt which is used only for Html project

Verify that you are using the right (jar file) /(extension library) : **gdx-box2d.jar** and **gdx-box2d-natives.jar** (also verify the build path)

also try :

upgrade the box2d version that you're using

those were all the arrows i had ! hope one of it will work

Good luck !!

Comment: Thank you! i was using the gwt libraries, so it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, was using the gwt libraries. Updated the Maven dependency artifact from

```
gdx-box2d-gwt
```

to

```
gdx-box2d
```

and it fixed the error.